# JavaFX: Setting count limit for an ObservableList fulfilling a condition

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I'll use an example to explain.

```
public class Person
{
    private final ObjectProperty<Gender> gender;
    public final ObjectProperty<Gender> genderProperty()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }
    public final void setGender(Gender value)
    {
        this.genderProperty().set(value);
    }
    public final Gender getGender()
    {
        return this.genderProperty().get();
    }

    public static enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE }

    /* Other properties */
}
```

Somewhere else...

```
public class MyClass
{
    private final ObservableList<Person> people;
    public final ObservableList<Person> getPeople()
    {
        return this.people;
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Create observable arraylist with extractor
        this.people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            person -> new Observable[]
                {
                    person.genderProperty()
                }
            );
    }
}
```

I need the `people` list to contain up to a maximum of 10 males, and a maximum of 5 females. Some of the `Person` object does not have the `gender` information when it is added to the `people` list, but my application must:

1. Pick up such a change when one of these `Person` object changes its `gender`, and the change happens to violate this limit.
2. Undo such a change so that my rule of 10 males / 5 females limits will always apply.

What can I do to ensure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you could add a new enum value in `Gender` that represents the unknown gender:

`public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE, UNKNOWN }`.

Then you can use a `ListChangeListener` like:

```
this.people = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person -> new Observable[] {person.genderProperty()});

 ListChangeListener<Person> listener = new ListChangeListener<Person>() {

    private boolean checkCondition(ObservableList<Person> list, Person.Gender gender) {
        int males = 0;
        int females = 0;

        for (Person person : list) {
            switch (person.getGender()) {
                case MALE: males++; break;
                case FEMALE: females++; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }

        return ((males > 10 && gender == Person.Gender.MALE) ||
                (females > 5 && gender == Person.Gender.FEMALE));
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends Person> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                for (Person person : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                    if (checkCondition((ObservableList<Person>) c.getList(), person.getGender()))
                        c.getList().remove(person);
                }
            }
            if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                for (int update = c.getFrom(); update < c.getTo(); update++) {
                    Person person = c.getList().get(update);
                    if (checkCondition((ObservableList<Person>) c.getList(), person.getGender()))
                        person.setGender(Person.Gender.UNKNOWN);
                }

            }
        }
    }
};

people.addListener(listener);
```

The only problem with this solution, that it does not really "revert" the update change, but sets the gender to the new unknown value.

---

If you want to really revert the change, the solution can be something like:

```
this.people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 ListChangeListener<Person> listener = new ListChangeListener<Person>() {

    private boolean checkCondition(ObservableList<Person> list, Person.Gender gender) {
        int males = 0;
        int females = 0;

        for (Person person : list) {
            switch (person.getGender()) {
                case MALE: males++; break;
                case FEMALE: females++; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }

        return ((males > 10 && gender == Person.Gender.MALE) ||
                (females > 5 && gender == Person.Gender.FEMALE));
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends Person> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                for (Person person : c.getAddedSubList()) {

                    if (checkCondition((ObservableList<Person>) c.getList(), person.getGender()))
                        c.getList().remove(person);
                    else
                        person.genderProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> {
                            if (checkCondition((ObservableList<Person>) c.getList(), newval))
                                person.setGender(oldval);
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

people.addListener(listener);
```

Differences: the extractor has been removed, as inside of the `ListChangeListener` only the addition of the elements are covered. When a new element is added, a listener on its `genderProperty` has been added which one checks to the gender update, and if the conditions are not met, the gener is reverted to be the original one.

---

You can also achieve the same functionality by not exposing the list, but methods that manipulate the list: `addPersonAt`, `removePersonAt` and `updateGenderAt`.

Comment: I think the second option would work great for me. Thanks!